# JENA: Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html

Tags: java, sparql, jena

When I try to send a sparql query to some endpoint, for example:

```
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://data.open.ac.uk/sparql",
                getStringForQuery());
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryException: Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html which is not currently supported for SELECT queries
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:372)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:334)
```

And this is not the only one endpoint, to which I can't send query,

What should I do to get results in other content-type? I try to google it, but I found that it can happen if I send query to bad html (not sparql endpoint), but http://data.open.ac.uk/sparql is good endpoint, I send sparql query to it via python and everything was good.

Comment: This should not happen since Jena is asking for a resultset compatible return type by default. Can you post the query please, i.e. the value of the method `getStringForQuery()`? It looks more like you're sending an illegal query to the endpoint, which leads to an error returned. And which Jena version do you use?

Comment: @AKSW I use jena 3.1.1, and I try to send some queries (all I verify in sparql editor on the site). For example, getStringForQuery() can return "select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 100". But now the site doesn't work :(

Comment: @AKSW Now the site is working

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what kind of backend they use, but for whatever reason, you have to use an additional HTTP parameter `force=true` when using the SPARQL endpoint from external services:

http://data.open.ac.uk/sparql?force=true

### Update:

According to Andy Seaborne from the Apache Jena development team, this is supposed to be a bug in the redirect in Jena 3.1.1. In version 3.1.0 the redirect to `?force=true` works as expected. In addition, the backend is Fuseki 2.3.1.