# Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html which is not rcognized for SELECT queries

Tags: tree, graphql, sparql

> [This is the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785145/extract-all-parents-of-a-given-node) (This is the 2nd part).

I'm using [HyperGraphQL](https://www.hypergraphql.org/) to query the [EBI-RDF sparql endpoint](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/rdf/services/sparql) based on [this tutorial](https://www.hypergraphql.org/tutorial/).

When I execute this GraphQL query to retrieve the parents of `GO_0044727` :

```
{
  Class_GET_BY_ID(uris:[
    "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0044727"]) {
    id
    label
    subClassOf {
      id
      label
      subClassOf {
        id
        label
        subClassOf {  # <--- 4th sub level
          id
          label
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got no results:

```
{
  "extensions": {},
  "data": {
    "@context": {
      "_type": "@type",
      "_id": "@id",
      "label": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label",
      "id": "http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#id",
      "Class_GET_BY_ID": "http://hypergraphql.org/query/Class_GET_BY_ID",
      "subClassOf": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"
    },
    "Class_GET_BY_ID": []
  },
  "errors": []
}
```

In the logs I got the error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.jena.query.QueryException: Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html which is not rcognized for SELECT queries
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.services.SPARQLEndpointService.iterateFutureResults(SPARQLEndpointService.java:86)
    at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.services.SPARQLEndpointService.executeQuery(SPARQLEndpointService.java:69)
    at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.ExecutionTreeNode.generateTreeModel(ExecutionTreeNode.java:357)
    at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.FetchingExecution.call(FetchingExecution.java:21)
    at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.FetchingExecution.call(FetchingExecution.java:8)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.jena.query.QueryException: Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html which is not rcognized for SELECT queries
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:377)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:344)
    at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.SPARQLEndpointExecution.call(SPARQLEndpointExecution.java:81)
    at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.SPARQLEndpointExecution.call(SPARQLEndpointExecution.java:33)
    ... 4 more
```

The SPARQL query generated based on the GraphQL query above:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE { 
    GRAPH <http://rdf.ebi.ac.uk/dataset/go> { 
        VALUES ?x_1 { <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0044727> } 
        ?x_1 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> . 
        OPTIONAL { 
            ?x_1 <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> ?x_1_1 .?x_1_1 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> . 
            OPTIONAL { ?x_1_1 <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?x_1_1_1 . }  
                OPTIONAL { ?x_1_1 <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> ?x_1_1_2 .?x_1_1_2 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> . 
                OPTIONAL { ?x_1_1_2 <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#id> ?x_1_1_2_1 . }  
                OPTIONAL { 
                    ?x_1_1_2 <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> ?x_1_1_2_2 .?x_1_1_2_2 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> . 
                    OPTIONAL { ?x_1_1_2_2 <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?x_1_1_2_2_1 . }  
                    OPTIONAL { ?x_1_1_2_2 <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#id> ?x_1_1_2_2_2 . }  
                }  
                OPTIONAL { ?x_1_1_2 <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?x_1_1_2_3 . }  
            }  
            OPTIONAL { ?x_1_1 <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#id> ?x_1_1_3 . }  
        }  
        OPTIONAL { ?x_1 <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?x_1_2 . }  
        OPTIONAL { ?x_1 <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#id> ?x_1_3 . }  
    }  
}
```

I tried @AKSW answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41931479/4488332) by adding `?force` in the `config.json` file (line: `"url": "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/rdf/services/sparql?force"`) but it didn't work.

I thought that maybe the query is too long but when I [tested the query](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/rdf/services/sparql?query=SELECT+*+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A%09GRAPH+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Frdf.ebi.ac.uk%2Fdataset%2Fgo%3E+%7B+%0D%0A%09%09VALUES+%3Fx_1+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FGO_0044727%3E+%7D+%0D%0A%09%09%3Fx_1+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23Class%3E+.+%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%0D%0A%09%09%09%3Fx_1+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subClassOf%3E+%3Fx_1_1+.%3Fx_1_1+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23Class%3E+.+%0D%0A%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fx_1_1+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E+%3Fx_1_1_1+.+%7D++%0D%0A%09%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fx_1_1+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subClassOf%3E+%3Fx_1_1_2+.%3Fx_1_1_2+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23Class%3E+.+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fx_1_1_2+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.geneontology.org%2Fformats%2FoboInOwl%23id%3E+%3Fx_1_1_2_1+.+%7D++%0D%0A%09%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%3Fx_1_1_2+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23subClassOf%3E+%3Fx_1_1_2_2+.%3Fx_1_1_2_2+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23type%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23Class%3E+.+%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fx_1_1_2_2+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E+%3Fx_1_1_2_2_1+.+%7D++%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fx_1_1_2_2+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.geneontology.org%2Fformats%2FoboInOwl%23id%3E+%3Fx_1_1_2_2_2+.+%7D++%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D++%0D%0A%09%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fx_1_1_2+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E+%3Fx_1_1_2_3+.+%7D++%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D++%0D%0A%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fx_1_1+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.geneontology.org%2Fformats%2FoboInOwl%23id%3E+%3Fx_1_1_3+.+%7D++%0D%0A%09%09%7D++%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fx_1+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E+%3Fx_1_2+.+%7D++%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fx_1+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.geneontology.org%2Fformats%2FoboInOwl%23id%3E+%3Fx_1_3+.+%7D++%0D%0A%09%7D++%0D%0A%7D&render=HTML&limit=25&offset=0#loadstar-results-section), it didn't give any error.

Comment: 1. `?force=true` (or `?force`) is not a valid query argument against a Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint (and may well be stripped by the proxy form provided by EMBL-EBI). 2. EMBL-EBI limits the serializations they'll deliver for SPARQL `SELECT` queries; I believe JSON will serve you. 3. I suggest you look into the docs of [Lodestar](http://ebispot.github.io/lodestar/) (the "Linked Data Browser and SPARQL endpoint" that EMBL-EBI has chosen to put in front of Virtuoso's SPARQL and other Linked Data endpoints) to find out how to get one of the serialization formats supported by HyperGraphQL.

Comment: @TallTed, Thank you for the clarifications, I checked out [Lodestar](http://ebispot.github.io/lodestar/) documentation but I couldn't find anything that can help me solve this issue. so I had to do the extraction locally (see my answer below for more details).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to query the Gene ontology using a [local RDF file](https://www.hypergraphql.org/documentation/):

1. I Downloaded [go.owl](http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/go.owl) file.
2. Converted it to Turtle using the [Ontology Converter](https://github.com/sszuev/ont-converter).

   ```
    java -jar ont-converter.jar -i go.owl -o go_ont.ttl -of ttl -v
   ```
3. Configured HyperGraphQL:

   The `goconfig.json` file:

   ```
   {
       "name": "go-hgql",
       "schema": "schemas/goschema.graphql",
       "server": {
           "port": 8082,
           "graphql": "/graphql",
           "graphiql": "/graphiql"
       },
       "services": [
           {
               "id": "go-local",
               "type": "LocalModelSPARQLService",
               "filepath": "go_ont.ttl",  # <----- the TTL file
               "filetype": "TTL"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   The `goschema.graphql`:

   ```
   type __Context {
       Class:          _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class")
       id:             _@href(iri: "http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#id")
       label:          _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label")
       subClassOf:     _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf")
   }

   type Class @service(id:"go-local") {
       id: [String] @service(id:"go-local")
       label: [String] @service(id:"go-local")
       subClassOf: [Class] @service(id:"go-local")
   }
   ```
4. Started HyperGraphQL using the config file:

   ```
   java -jar build/libs/hypergraphql-1.0.3-exe.jar --config hgql/config/goconfig.json
   ```
5. Then executed the query, and it went fine without problems, I could add as many sublevels as I needed.

Comment: I urge you to send feedback to the EMBL-EBI team about this. It's not clear what benefit Lodestar is delivering, and it's definitely blocking some features of Virtuoso. It should not be necessary for you to grab the whole data dump just to execute this sort of query.